# git stash apply/pop, but forgot --index

Tags: git

Situation:

- local git checkout of branch `main` with both staged and non-staged changes
- `git stash`
- ... work on other branches, etc ...
- `git checkout main`
- `git stash apply`  <- NOTE the accidentally missing `--index`

How can I now (without major git surgery...) recover the missing **staged** changes, i.e. the state if I *would* have gotten, had I correctly used `git stash apply --index` above?

And, ideally, I don't want to re-resolve any conflicts already dealt with after the problematic `git stash apply` command.

Comment: The fact that you used `apply` instead of `pop` means you still have the stash. So, if your `git checkout main` left you with a *clean* setup, you can just `git reset --hard` now to get back to that clean checkout of `main`, and then run `git stash apply --index` and you're done. But if the "work on other branches, etc" step left uncommitted changes that you carried over to `main` with `git checkout main` and you want to *keep* those changes *too*, now you have a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a stash named `stash@{0}`, do:

```
git read-tree stash@{0}^2
```

This changes *only* the index (aka. staging area), so `git reset` will 'undo' it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that right now your staged changes are mixed with the stashed changes and you want to separate them.
Do the following:

1. commit all your changes in one commit on main branch
   `git add -A && git commit -m "Save stash mixed with staged"`
2. go back once without hard resetting the HEAD
   `git checkout HEAD~1`
3. create a temp branch
   `git checkout -b temp`
4. Get your stashed changes on this temp branch
   `git stash apply`
5. commit the stashed changes on this branch
   `git add -A && git commit -m "Save stashed changes temporarily"`
6. Get your staged changes now
   `git reset --soft main`
7. Now you have your staged changes visible in front of you, so stash them
   `git stash save "staged_changes"`
8. Go back to main
   git checkout main
9. `git reset --hard HEAD~1`
10. `git stash pop`
    and your staged changes will be visible again

I hope this helps ;)